# How do I write that $f(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$ almost everywhere using $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)$

Tags: notation

As the title says, I have a function, which vanishes for increasing time almost everywhere. For example take the function

$$  \begin{equation} \label{markov}
    f(t) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
     \frac{1}{t} &\text{for } t \in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}, \\
     1 &\text{else}.
    \end{array}
    \right.
  \end{equation}$$
Now, for increasing time, $f$ goes to $0$ for almost all $t$, but for natural arguments $f$ is constant $1$. 
I guess i cannot write $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t) = 0 \quad \text{almost everywhere.}$$
But how can i write this?

Comment: Well, you cerainly don't want to write "$f\to0$ as $t\to\f\infty$ almost everywhere"; that doesn't really make sense. You might define $S=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb N$ and then say $\lim_{S\ni t\to\infty}f(t)=0$. (That backeards "in" is spelled \ni.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that one usually defines almost everywhere convergence for a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. But I think we can get what you want by imitating the notion of $\liminf $ and $\limsup$.

In the comment by David C. Ullrich, one has to know the negligible subset preventing $f$ from converging. Without this data a priori, one could look at
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} \big( \underset{s\geq t}{\operatorname{ess inf}} f(s)\big)\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{t\to\infty} \big( \underset{s\geq t}{\operatorname{ess sup}} f(s)\big)$$
If they coincide, then this value is the limit, otherwise there is no limit.

The **essential infimum** or **supremum** (here on $\mathbb{R}$) are defined by
$$\underset{s\in \mathbb{R}}{\operatorname{ess inf}} f(s) := \sup \big\lbrace m\in \mathbb{R},\ f^{-1}\big(]-\infty,m[ \big)\ \text{negligible}\big\rbrace \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$\underset{s\in \mathbb{R}}{\operatorname{ess sup}} f(s) := \inf\big\lbrace M\in \mathbb{R},\ f^{-1}\big(]M,+\infty[ \big)\ \text{negligible}\big\rbrace \tag{2}\label{2}$$
(In comparison, the infimum is the "greatest lower bound" and the supremum is the "least upper bound", i.e.
$$\inf_{s\in \mathbb{R}} f(s) := \max\big\lbrace m\in \mathbb{R},\ f^{-1}\big(]-\infty,m[ \big)=\emptyset\big\rbrace$$
$$\sup_{s\in \mathbb{R}} f(s) := \min\big\lbrace M\in \mathbb{R},\ f^{-1}\big(]M,+\infty[ \big)=\emptyset\big\rbrace$$
I'm not exactly sure if one really needs $\inf$ and $\sup$ in (\ref{1},\ref{2}) or if one could put $\min$ and $\max$, but this is left to the reader...)